# How to convert black and white image to array with 3 dimensions in python?

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing, computer-vision

I have image in either RGB format or grayscale format (I converted it through Gimp, let's say), now everytime I load the image in grayscale, or just transform it to grayscale format, the shape always says [height, width] without the third dimension (number of color channels).

I know that usually b/w images are stored in such format, but I specifically need the `[height, width, 1]` image shape, the one you would get with, let's say:

```
numpy.zeros(shape=[400, 400, 1])
```

Comment: Did either of the posted solution work for you?

Comment: Yes, both solutions worked, I forgot to mark one of them as accpted, thanks for reminder!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can always add "empty" dimensions using [`np.expand_dims`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html):

```
>>> a2d = np.ones((100, 200))
>>> a3d = np.expand_dims(a2d, axis=2)
>>> a3d.shape
(100, 200, 1)
```

or by slicing with `None` or `np.newaxis`:

```
>>> a2d[..., None].shape  # instead of "..." (Ellipsis) you could also use `[:, :, None]`
(100, 200, 1)
```

I prefer `np.expand_dims` because it's a bit more explicit about what happens than slicing.

---

If you need it conditionally, check for `arr.ndim` first:

```
if arr.ndim == 2:
    arr = np.expand_dims(arr, axis=2)
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a built-in [`np.atleast_3d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_3d.html) exactly for this purpose -

```
np.atleast_3d(img)
```

This built-in takes care of keeping the output shape to be `3D` by appending one new axis as the last one for a `2D` array and makes no change for a `3D` input, all being taken care of under the hoods.

Sample run -

```
In [42]: img = np.random.randint(0,255,(800,600)) # grayscale img

In [43]: np.atleast_3d(img).shape
Out[43]: (800, 600, 1)

In [44]: img = np.random.randint(0,255,(800,600,3)) # RGB img

In [45]: np.atleast_3d(img).shape
Out[45]: (800, 600, 3)
```

Comment: I only tried `np.array(img, ndmin=3, copy=False)` but that just prepends dimensions. Good to know they have another function for appending dimensions. :)

Comment: Another thing "that cares of it under the hoods" sounds wrong. Did you mean "that takes care of it ..."?

Comment: @MSeifert Was running short of words there. Edited to make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I used `np.reshape()` to add another dimension into grayscale image

```
grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(raw_data, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
print(grayscale.shape) # prints (800,600)

grayscale = grayscale.reshape(grayscale.shape[0], grayscale.shape[1], 1)
print(grayscale.shape) # prints (800,600,1)
```